# Ember nesting of components not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli project and my `application.hbs` setup looks like this.

```
 {{#site-navigation}}
    <h1>Welcome to turbo entertainment</h1>
 {{/site-navigation}}
```

`site-navigation` is a component which looks like this

```
{{#nav-bar}}{{/nav-bar}}
  {{yield}}
{{#nav-footer}}{{/nav-footer}}
```

The problem is that `<h1>Welcome to turbo entertainment</h1>` get rendered perfectly fine but 
my `nav-bar` and `nav-footer` don't show up at all. Here's the rendered html

```
<div id="ember287" class="ember-view">
  <div id="ember316" class="ember-view site-navigation-view">
    <h1>this is helix entertainment</h1>
 </div> 
</div>
```

I have added `classNames:[whateverThisComponentIs-view]` to every of my component so I can identify the rendering. But as visible, I don't see a container named `nav-bar-view` or `nav-footer-view`.

I am on ember-cli --version 0.1.4

Comment: What version of Ember is it?

Comment: Can you show the navbar and nav footer code/templates as well?

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was some of the node modules were not properly installed. I basically removed the app and restarted the whole project, making sure I did `npm update` on the whole thing. That worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're yielding

```
<h1>Welcome to turbo entertainment</h1>
```

to the site-navigation component but when it gets rendered you're seeing

```
<h1>this is helix entertainment</h1>
```

Was this a mistake in composing the question? If not, are you sure you're debugging the correct app or correct version of the app? If you're using liveReload with ember cli make sure you restart ember serve to ensure that everything is compiled properly and all your templates are up to date.